# Bad exc error when using Google Analytics 2.0 B4

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, google-analytics-api

Sample project, with Google Analytics usage
[Xcode Project][1]

Actually i have create a phoneplugin for google analytics. My code seems to be working fine, but when i tried adding my code to an existing project , i am getting bad exc error. I really cant find why can the code work on a new project but doesnt work on a old project.

Code works really well in a new project. I can see the data in analytics dashboard and everything works fine in it

Comment: Can you post some code for how you are setting up Google Analytics, and anything you may be logging that has a time interval as that looks like the crash? I suspect you are giving GA bad data.

Comment: Hi jack, what codes you want to see. I cant post entire code. If you specify a portion, i may post it here. There problem i face only with this project. The same code works very good when used in a new project. But it just this old project which is giving me error for same code.

Comment: I could attach the entire xcode project. of just the analytics code, if you want to see how i implement it. But i should remind you that the code will work in that project. But only this old project , causing me problem.

Comment: Is ARC enabled in the new project but not enabled in old one?

Comment: in both the projects ARC is not enabled

Comment: added implementation code

Comment: May you please attach all project?

Comment: It is must be because you are releasing an autoreleased object somewhere in your project. Look at the zombie profile and you will find that PaycorProj is responsible for retaining NSHTTPURLResponse's object 1 time and releasing it twice. You have to go through the projcect files and have to find wrong releases. Hope this helps.

Comment: added xcode project file

Answer (score 1):

following the documentation :

First you will need a Google Analytics tracking ID to track application usage with the
SDK.

Second continue by adding the header files (GAI.h, GAITracker.h,
GAITransaction.h, and GAITransactionItem.h) and libGoogleAnalytics.a to your
XCode project. Your app must link the following frameworks:
 1- CoreData.framework
 2- SystemConfiguration.framework

NB:To use a version of the library with debug symbols intact, link against
libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a instead of libGoogleAnalytics.a. This may be useful
if you experience exceptions or crashes originating in the SDK.

BR